QGIS: Horizontal alignment of legend symbol to multi-line label
Using QGIS 3.28.15
I have a legend label that is spanning over multiple lines. Can I horziontally align the coresponding (non-simple fill) symbol to appear in the center of the label?


Simple symbols
For simple symbols you can use a custom symbol for the layer and apply a vertical (Y) offset.
Double click the layer name in the Legend Properties to open the Legend Item Properties.
Enable Custom Symbol with the check box, then click on the symbol button.

Select the Symbol Layer (in this case Simple Fill) and apply the offset. A positive offset moveds the symbol downwards.


Non-simple symbols
For non-simple symbols you can leverage the Transform Draw Effect to shift each symbol layer individually.
Again, in the Legend Item Properties > Symbol Settings, for each Symbol Layer check the Draw Effects checkbox and click the  button.

Select Transform as the Effect type and apply the Y translation.

Once all symbol layers have the Y translation, they will appear correctly relative to each other.


Thanks Matt! This indeed does the job for symbols based on simple fills. However, I do not have the possibility to adjust a vertical offset for a symbol based on simple lines...
Any idea for that case?

For a simple line, make the same kind of offset as suggested above but using the offset parameter that should be in between Stroke width and Stroke style.

Unfortunately, for me this doesn't create the intended effect. The offset parameter between stroke width and stroke style shifts the outline into the inner (for positive offsets) or into the outer (for negative aspects). Additionally, there is only one offset to set, so I could not handle a specific y- or x-offset.

Indeed, I thought you were working with a simple line not a polygon with a simple line border.

Ah sry, then I was to unspecific :)

Hopefully, my updated answer works for you. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear possible to shift the whole symbol at once, but rather each Symbol Layer individually.

Here is one solution that I am using now for non-simple symbols.
Within the legend item properties I adjust the Patch Height of the symbol to span over my multi-line labelling.

This is the resulting legend. Not exactly what I intended but more appealing than having a tpo-aligned symbol.

